# Cannot remove McAffee off my computer

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I installed McAffee a while ago and just realized it is still running through my task manager. Using task manager's "go to file location" I found the exe is running from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\mcafee\SystemCore`.

Trying to delete it doesn't work as I "don't have permission." So I then tried (as an administrator):

- giving myself permission through the properties
- giving myself permission through `takeown`
- giving myself permission through `icacls`
- giving myself permission using "Unlocker"

Everything I tried just leads to an "Access is denied" error.

I even tried using `takeown` with system permissions using [PsTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to no avail.

I don't know what else I could possibly do- at this point, the program is behaving as malware.

I would rather not use McAfee's removal tool so I want to try everything else possible beforehand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"I would rather not use McAfee's removal tool"_ - why? It's exactly what you need. There's probably more junk here and there around the system that you don't know of, but the tool will delete.

Comment: @gronostaj It just feels like more bloatware, which is exactly what I'm trying to remove- I'll use it if I have no other options but I'm just looking to see if there's anything else I can do first

Comment: @John Once again I'm asking you to read questions more carefully before posting.